# How to use AngularJS $submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

On submit, AngularJS sets `$submitted` on the `FormController` and adds the class `ng-submitted` to the form. That's nice, and I could add

```
ng-disabled="myForm.$submitted || myForm.$invalid || maybeAnotherCondition"
```

to the submit button, and disable all inputs (as there's no point in re-submitting or editing anything before the call returns). The inputs should probably be re-enabled as soon as the call returns and the submit button on the first following input change...

Quite a lot of things to do and before I start with it, I'd like to know, if there's already some pattern or even a directive doing all this stuff? I could imagine having something like

```
FormService.manage(form, onSubmit, onSuccess, onFailure)
```

where each of the three functions would do *just the specific job* and nothing of the above boilerplate.

Comment: Were you able to disable a single input field and now want to disable all the input fields?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I did nothing yet as I'm looking for a simple solution to be applied to all my forms. I don't want to pollute all inputs with `ng-disabled`. Using the `fieldset` is helpful, but I'm looking for more.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write a directive that will do things for you like I did in one of my directive https://github.com/sagrawal14/bootstrap-angular-validation/blob/master/src/directives/form.directive.js to apply global Bootstrap validation like jQuery in my many forms without writing anything extra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable all the input fields at once, I would suggest you use `<fieldset>`.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" ng-submit="someHandler()">
    <fieldset form="myForm" ng-disabled="myForm.$submitted || myForm.$invalid || maybeAnotherCondition">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="firstName" />

        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" data-ng-model="lastName" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Disabling the `fieldset` element will disable all it's child input elements. See a working example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.submitHandler = function() {
    alert("Form submitted");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController" class="container">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" ng-submit="submitHandler()">
    <fieldset form="myForm" ng-disabled="myForm.$submitted">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="firstName" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" data-ng-model="lastName" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{myForm.$submitted ? 'Submitted' : 'Submit'}}
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I like you answer (because of the `fieldset` information and because of runnable code), but what helped me most was the directive from your `bootstrap.angular.validation` module.

Comment: @maaartinus Oh great!! Glad that helped you.